# Calling Perl GetOptions twice does not work as expected

Tags: perl

I'm struggling to find a Perl GetOptions reference that explains this behavior.

If I call GetOptions twice then the 2nd time I call it, it fails to parse the command-line parameters and they're all returned undefined.  Did the 1st call to GetOptions (which, by the way, failed and returned 0) eat the command-line parameters or did the 2nd call simply decide not to bother parsing because it remembered that it had previously failed?

Don't ask why I'm calling GetOptions twice -- it's because the code would be complex to restructure and I'd prefer not to unless necessary.  I just want a simple way, in advance of the 'real' call to GetOptions, to test for the presence of a single command-line parameter.  Thanks.

Comment: See Penfold's comment on my answer. That might be exactly what you need.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`GetOptions` *consumes and modifies* the `@ARGV` array. After calling that function, all that's usually left in that array are the file-name parameters.

If you don't store a copy of the array so you can reset it later, then subsequent `GetOptions` calls will have nothing left to parse. You can try calling `GetOptionsFromArray` with an arbitrary array instead of using the implicit `@ARGV`, too.

Answer (score 5):

`GetOptions` removes the options from `@ARGV`, leaving you with only the actual arguments, so that the rest of your program doesn't have to be aware of the options when it deals with `@ARGV`. I don't see this explicitly mentioned in the documentation, but it's how option parsers generally work.

This does mean that calling it a second time is going to be pretty useless, unless you have some complex schema for options like this: `--section1-opt1 --section1-opt2 -- --section2-opt1 --section1-opt2 -- <real arguments>`. The first call would eat up to the first terminating `--`, and the second would parse the next section up to the second `--`. I can't imagine that being the friendliest of interfaces, though.

Comment: use a recent Getopt::Long, and do "use Getopt::Long qw/pass_through/;" - your first call to GetOptions then will only remove the options from @ARGV that it knows about, rather than all of them.

Answer (score 3):

As [already pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4739359/calling-perl-getoptions-twice-does-not-work-as-expected/4739389#4739389), `@ARGV` is modified by `GetOptions`. Although not a pretty sight, you can declare `@ARGV` local:

```
{
local(@ARGV) = @ARGV;
GetOptions(...);
}

# @ARGV "restored" here    
GetOptions(...);
```

Comment: Might as well just copy `@ARGV` and use `GetOptionsFromArray` at this point - it'll be more clear.

Comment: @Jefromi I didn't mention that (although, I possibly should have), because the OP says, that the code is "too complex to restructure"

Comment: The restructuring the OP's referring to is eliminating one call altogether. Changing `GetOptions(...)` to `my @foo = @ARGV; GetOptionsFromArray(\@foo, ...);` is not a restructuring, any more than declaring `@ARGV` local is.

Comment: Appreciate all the feedback, thanks.  I think I'll just test the contents of ARGV for the one parameter that I'm looking for, rather than try to call GetOptions twice.