# perl, saving the command line option

Tags: perl

I have this perl script and it takes in arguments using the getoption package.

Is there an easy way to document what was the exact command the user used to execute?

I would like to document into a log file.

Gordon

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `$0` and `@ARGV` together:

```
my $full_command = join(' ', $0, @ARGV);
```

Comment: According to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4739359/calling-perl-getoptions-twice-does-not-work-as-expected/4739389#4739389, it's worth noting that `GetOptions` might modify `@ARGV`. If that is the case, you will need to store the original `@ARGV` somewhere else before using `GetOptions`.

Comment: If you set up $full_command=join(' ', $0, @ARGV); within a BEGIN{} block it inspects @ARGV before Getopt::Long has a chance to mutilate it.  Just be sure to declare 'my $full_command' earlier in the script than the physical location of the BEGIN{} block.

Comment: @DavidO, you don't need a BEGIN block unless you're calling `GetOptions` in a BEGIN block.  Simply loading Getopt::Long doesn't do anything to `@ARGV`.

Comment: The big problem with this answer is that any spaces in `@ARGV` will appear to separate arguments.  That is, you can't tell the difference between `foo bar` and `'foo bar'` (2 arguments or 1 argument with space).  You could use [String::ShellQuote](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?String::ShellQuote) to fix that.

Answer (score 5):

or you can simply

```
my $full;
BEGIN { $full = "$0 @ARGV" }
#
print "log: $full\n";
```

[form the perlvar](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html)

```
$LIST_SEPARATOR
$"
```

> When an array or an array slice is
>   interpolated into a double-quoted
>   string or a similar context such as
>   /.../ , its elements are separated by
>   this value. Default is a space. For
>   example, this:

```
print "The array is: @array\n";
```

> is equivalent to this:

```
print "The array is: " . join($", @array) . "\n";
```

Comment: Won't that mush all of `@ARGV` together with no space?

Comment: try it. ;) will join with default separator.

Comment: Well, that's my point-- what's the default separator? perlvar says `undef`.

Comment: simply try it. it is like BEGIN { $full = qq{$0 @ARGV} } what will work too.

Comment: @Platinum perlvar says for $" 'Default is a space'. You must have looked up the wrong variable.

Comment: Damn it. I was looking at `$,`